# What does "make your night a living hell" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Ortiz also accuses Lettman of illegally filming him and says, “So, I’m going to make sure, while you’re recording this, that you never have a job as a Lyft driver again.” When Lettman finally speaks, he points to a sign in his car that states passengers will be recorded, to which Ortiz threatens to “**make your night a living hell**.”

According to dictionaries, **a living hell** means "*An extremely unpleasant situation*". But I'm not quite sure “**make your night a living hell**”, as a whole, is conveying. It seems to be a metaphor of some kind.

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/trump-supporter-calls-911-black-lyft-driver-not-turning-radio-225018422.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Make your night a living hell

Would imply that the person will make the other person entire night very unpleasant and most likely tormenting.

It is of no deeper meaning that simply making the other party feel very unpleasant.